# How to start a specific stage in a release using Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I came around [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API to create a release.

But there seems to be no property in the request body where I can specific a certain stage to be released?

Is there another way I can do it?

Comment: How do you do it in the UI? when you create release all the stages start to run (according to the triggers). or do you mean where you create release you can move stages from automatic to manual?

Comment: You can always trigger a release and a stage manually I want to mimic that using the api.

Comment: Do you mean that all your stages are manually, you create a release (now nothing run because all it's manual) and then run a stage?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: OK, check my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to create the release with the API you provided, after that, you need to use the [Update Release Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API to start the stage (environment = stage):

```
PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.6
```

Body:

```
{
  "status": "inProgress",
  "scheduledDeploymentTime": null,
  "comment": null,
  "variables": {}
}
```