# Is it possible to revert Azure DevOps release deployment if UI automation test (in Cucumber) does not pass?

Tags: azure-devops, cucumber

There is a 3 Tier application. The UI code in React is deployed in Azure Blob storage as static website. The backend services are deployed in Azure App services. We have Azure APIM as internet facing service to have access to APIs.

The release pipeline deploys build to DEV, QA (Staging) and PROD environments. Deployment to QA is based on approval after merge to master branch.

Once QA deployment stage is completed, Automation test written in Java Cucumber framework is executed which opens a headless chrome browser in Azure Agent and runs the test cases.

Automation test Tasks:
[image]

Is it possible to revert the UI build in QA environment if Automation test does not pass using Azure DevOps ?

Since the UI build is uploaded to Azure Blob container in CD pipeline, we could not find a way to automatically revert to earlier build by replacing the static files.

[image]

Frontend Build Tasks look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to revert the UI build in QA environment if Automation test does not pass using Azure DevOps ?

There could be two aspect code: DevOps pipeline source code and remote azure resource(azure storage account).

If your QA stage and Automation test doesn't update the DevOps source code, you can ignore, as next build will get the source code again. If it does, you have to restore the git.

I suspect you would like to revert the azure resource storage account data, if so, you can add a new stage/job, add [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#conditions) to monitor the Automation test result, use powershell command or azure cli to [restore the azure storage data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-manage?tabs=powershell).

In addition, directly update the resource could be not a good option, would suggest to check the deployment on a test environment(new branch, test azure storage account). Once it's OK, you can deploy to production resource.

Edit:

> I was wondering if it is possible to deploy Azure previous stage using PowerShell script? Also, the automation test result is published as Maven Surefire plugin ((maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/…) , how do I parse them and take decision to run the next stage.

1. You can use rest api [Releases - Update Release Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to rerun the specific stage. You can find similar answer in link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57659385/14996050). In the rest api uri, you can use [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release) to get the release id and environment id(eg: `$(Release.EnvironmentId)`, `$(Release.ReleaseId)`).
2. If the automation test task failed, you can directly add a new task which depends on it(only run when test task fails), execute the re-run stage script above.
3. If the automation test task shows succeed status, the test only fails in the result, you need to parse the test result file `Test-*.xml` which generated by the maven task, you can check my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68826981/14996050) for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but I was wondering if it is possible to deploy Azure previous stage using PowerShell script? Also, the automation test result is published as Maven Surefire plugin ((https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) , how do I parse them and take decision to run the next stage ?

Comment: Hi @IndraChatterjee, i have updated my answer, please have a check. Please note when you re-run the pipeline, make sure the previous run didn't update the codes(source or remote), or re-run can overwrite the codes.